Has there ever been a country in which the people have decided that they didn't want a monarchy and the king/queen has stepped down without bloodshed?
The only examples I can think of are commonwealth (of the UK) countries who chose not to have the UK monarch as head of state which is not the same thing.
I want the name of a country where "the people" decided that they no longer wanted a monarch, hereditary chief, leader, whatever. And that leader listened and left without a war. Has it ever happened cos I don't think it has

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). USA/George Washington is a potential example, but (a) I'm not sure what "the people" are, or how they express their desire and (b) I'm not sure how this would take place.

The Philippine People Power Revolution comes to mind, although there was rather a lot of violence out of the ruler before the revolution proper. Strongmen be violent.

Does this answer your question: Has there ever been a peaceful overthrow of a dictator or monarch?

@LarsBosteen - Honestly don't see the difference in the questions myself, and the possible dup has a lot of highly-rated answers (I even made the exact same comment as the one above there!) Tempted to just close it myself on that basis, but it would be too ironic on this question, so you all should vote on it instead. :-)

Several - Greece in 1924 and Italy in 1946 are perhaps the best European examples where we know what people (and how many of them) really wanted. Both kings stepped down somewhat unhappily, but without bloodshed.

Even more clear: the Second Spanish Republic. After local elections in 1931 that were commonly understood as having been won by the republican parties, the Republic was declared. Alfonso XIII. acepted that he "no longer had the love of his people" and left the country, albeit without formally abdicating.

Regarding Greece: Between 1924 and 1974 there were five referendums about the question "Republik and Monarchy", with various outcomes.

@ccprog Yes  - but those other Greek referenda fail other points of the question. Either they were rigged, there was some bloodshed, or the king was  already powerless and/or in exile.

If you see Italy's case in the context of Mussolini and the partition of Italy between pro-Axis and pro-Allied sides, it is difficult to call it "without bloodshed"

Tunisia
Tunisia had been a French protectorate from 1881 to 1956. The withdrawal of the French happened with the expectation that Tunisia was to become a monarchy, and on 20 March 1956, Lamine Bey, the Bey of Tunis, was proclaimed as King Muhammad VIII.
One week later, the National Constituent Assembly was elected. You might question its democratic character, but fact is that the National Union alliance won all 98 seats and the appointed Prime Minister, Habib Bourguiba, lead a government dominated by his own Neo Destour party.
Over the course of the next year, the rights and possessions of the king were more and more restricted, culminating in a de-facto house arrest from 15 July 1957 on.
On 25 July 1957, the National Constituent Assembly convened to decide over the form of government and declared Tunesia to be a Republic. On the same evening, the royal family were made aware of the decision and asked to leave the palace. He spent the time until his release in 1960 in house arrest.
Muhammad, 75 years old at the time, did not resist any of the measures against him.


Has there ever been a country in which the people have decided that they didn't want a monarchy and the king/queen has stepped down without bloodshed?

(emphasis is mine)
How do "people" decide?
The catch here is what it means people have decided. Strictly speaking it implies that people could vote in a referendum to decide whether they want the continuation of the monarchy/regime. I won't claim that this is impossible, but, if the population is already given this level of political freedom, it is unlikely to be much interested in the regime change. On the other hand, if the referendum is illegal, then we cannot meaningfully speak of the people deciding.
Non-violent revolutions
People have decided is often used as an euphemism (by media and politicians) intended to legitimize revolutions or even coup d'état. Wikipedia provides a list of non-violent revolutions, i.e., the regime changes that did not involve a civil war or an open military confrontation between the regime and the revolutionaries, claiming to represent "the people". E.g., Arab Spring is a relatively recent series of events that included non-violent revolutions in Tunisia and Egypt. However one cannot claim with certainty that the popular protests that led to these regime changes represented "the people" and not merely a "vocal minority".
Note also that these were not strictly non-violent - people often die in popular protests  - e.g., hundreds of people died in 2011 Egypt revolution, but this is treated as a "common crime" rather than a revolutionary violence, hence the revolution is viewed as peaceful.
Some of the outstings of the communist regimes in late 80s and early 90s also fit the definition of peaceful revolutions - like Velvet revolution or the Fall of the Berlin Wall.
An interesting case in this context is the peaceful fall of the USSR, which however occurred after a referendum where the majority of the population supposedly did support preservation of the USSR and the communist system.
Non-violent coup d'état (Soft coup)
Non-violent coup d'état is also not unknown.  Abdications of King Saud of Saudi Arabia or Nicholas II of Russia or removal of Khrushchev are but a few of many examples. These were also justified in the name of the "people", although the actual pressure on the monarch and the decisions were made by a rather limited circle.
